# Determine that the function is surjective function or not?

Tags: functions

Determine that the function is surjective function or not ?

$$f(x)=\frac{1+x^6}{x^3}, f: D→R$$ where D is domain.

**My approach:-**
Since range of the function is R and co domain is also R so the given function must be surjective, But book say it is not surjective. Why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\frac{1+x^6}{x^3} = b \in \mathbb{R}$.
Then,
$$1+x^6 = bx^3 \implies x^6-bx^3+1 = 0.$$
Let $y = x^3$.  Then
$$y^2-by+1 = 0 \implies y = \frac{b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4}}{2}.$$
Let $b = 0$.  Then, this implies that $y$ is imaginary and $x$ is imaginary.
So, the function is not surjective.

Answer (score 0):

To show a function $A \to B$ is surjective you should try to show that for any abitrary element $b \in B$ that there exists an $a \in A$ such that $f(a) = b$.

To show a function is not surjective you only need to find some $b$ such that for all $a \in A$, $f(a) \neq b$. If you're having trouble with this step I recommend graphing the function using [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator) or some other graphing utility.

Comment: Drawing graph using Demos is not good idea because In our exam I.e IIT , even calculator does not provided to student, so can you tell a appropriate way to solve the question.